# PromiseKit branching promise

Tags: xcode, swift, promisekit

Suppose you have a branch in your promise chain that could either return nothing or an AnyObject promise. What would you specify as the return type of the 'then' closure? For example:

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        fulfill(1)
    }
    .then { _ -> Void in
        if false {
            return Promise { fulfill, reject in
                fulfill(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I put Void as the return type for the 'then' closure I get a seg fault; if I put Promise as return type then I get an error:

```
missing return in a closure expected to return Promise<AnyObject>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you use `Promise` as the return type, you must return a Promise. Right now you're only doing that from inside `if false`, which will never be executed.

Comment: If I change to `func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in
            fulfill(1)
        }.then { _ -> Void in
            debugPrint("foo")
        }.then { _ -> Promise<AnyObject> in
            if false {
                return Promise { fulfill, reject in
                    fulfill(0)
                }
            }

            return Promise { fulfill, reject in
                fulfill(0)
            }
        }
    }` it works; but it seems kinda lame that I have to explicitly return an empty promise @jtbandes

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you have this `if false` branch?

Comment: Just to clarify that the closure could either return void or a promise resolved to some object; I'm not clear on the implementation of the PromiseKit's 'then' method and what it does under the hood @jtbandes

Comment: "could either return void or a promise" => that's not possible in Swift. A function must have a single return type.

Comment: @jtbandes Yea I mispoke. Suppose its possible for the closure to return two different types; for example: 1) Promise<Anyobject> or 2) String. Im curious how you would indicate this in the closure return type

Comment: Like I said, there is no such thing. Perhaps you could use an enum instead.

Comment: @jtbandes Hmm, ok I see. Well I have to look into this some more. Thanks!

Comment: try returning an optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code sample, I see no reason to return an AnyObject. If you want to optionally return Void or an Object, then make a promise that contains an optional.

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject?> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        functionForGettingObjectWithCallback() { result: AnyObject? in
            fulfill(result)
        }
    }
}
```